# OnInitialUpdate called twice

Tags: c++, mfc

One of our MFC legacy applications shows a behavior I do not really understand right now. I am not an MFC expert, however. The symptom that I observe and which is causing problems is that [OnInitialUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc7fw3a0(v=vs.140).aspx) of the views is called twice by the framework during app start-up. As I understand the documentation it should be called only once.

My investigation revealed that the app calls the following code in its InitInstance:

```
CMainFrame *const pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;
if (!pMainFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME)) { return FALSE; }
m_pMainWnd = pMainFrame;
```

This causes `CFrameWnd::LoadFrame` being called inside the framework. From here both calls to [OnInitialUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc7fw3a0(v=vs.140).aspx) originate. The first when `Create` is called and the second when `SendMessageToDescendants` is called to send `WM_INITIALUPDATE`.

Our app overloads `CMainFrame::OnCreateClient` to create a splitter window:

```
Splitter.CreateStatic(this, 2, 2);
Splitter.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(MyView),CSize(0,0), pContext);
// ...
```

The call to `Splitter.CreateView` is what triggers [OnInitialUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc7fw3a0(v=vs.140).aspx) to be called the first time. But as I could see from the documentation this implementation is as intended. So unfortunately this is where I get stuck. I don't understand if the [OnInitialUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc7fw3a0(v=vs.140).aspx) call from `SendMessageToDescendants(WM_INITIALUPDATE, 0, 0, TRUE, TRUE)` or from `CSplitterWnd::CreateView` is wrong.

1. What else could I take a look at to figure out the root cause of this problem?
2. Is it possible for [OnInitialUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc7fw3a0(v=vs.140).aspx) to be called twice and we need to make sure that our app can cope with this?
3. If the answer to question 2 is yes: What is the best way to archive this?

---

**EDIT**

Further investigation has shown that `CSplitterWnd::CreateView` only sends `WM_INITIALUPDATE` if the passed `CCreateContext` is a nullptr. So I checked `CMainFrame::OnCreateClient` and it is indeed called by the framework with `pContext` being nullptr.

---

**EDIT2**

As requested in the comments here is the code adding the DocTemplate:

```
CSingleDocTemplate *const pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
    IDR_MAINFRAME,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMenuDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMenuView));
if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
```

There is also a call

```
Splitter.CreateView(1, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CMenuView),CSize(0,0), pContext);
```

in the `CMainFrame::OnCreateClient`. If I understand the comments correctly this is wrong?

The two calls of [OnInitialUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc7fw3a0(v=vs.140).aspx) are for the same instances of the views. If I followed the stack trace correctly the reason for the `CCreateContext` being a nullptr is that no context is passed to `LoadFrame`. The context passed to `CFrameWnd::LoadFrame` is just forwarded to `CMainFrame::OnCreateClient`. But what context should I pass?

Comment: Show us the code how you add your DocTemplate in your CWinApp:InitInstance(). Possible you have two instances of your MyView.

Comment: @TomTom Thanks for your comment. I added the requested code to the question.

Comment: For CSingleDoc Template there is no need to call  `new CMainFrame; ..->LoadFrame(..).   ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo)` does it allready all for you.

Comment: I would like to share my solution. Instead of creating a Single Doc project without Doc-View, just create one with Doc-View (and just leave these .cpp/.h unused). I regard this as a bug of VS wizard.